Network shares don't show up in 24.04
Just did a clean install of Ubuntu 24.04
My Synology NAS no longer shows up in other locations in files:

Manual connection works fine:

Does anyone know if something change since 23.10 and/or if there is any way to fix?

[edit] your question with the contents of /etc/fstab. Did you recreate the mount points?

@graham nothing in fstab besides root and efi, never had any custom mount points defined, the NAS always used to show up in networks

as an example, this is a line from my fstab //192.168.1.117/[share_name] /media/NAS/[share_name] cifs username=[username],password=[password],rw,uid=1000,gid=500 and then I created the mount point /media/NAS/[share_name]. Without creating the mount point yourself, the system allocates automatically (simple explanation). Of course edit your own share name in where I have put [share_name] in square brackets.  Hope that helps further. I don't have the 24.04 instance so this is from my 22.04 instance but should perform i n the same way.

@graham yeah I should probably setup a persistent mount for regular stuff... But this doesn't solve network discovery for the stuff I only want to access from time to time

Note: I do not have your NAS so this is just general information.
There are a number of changes to network discovery in 24.04. You will notice there is no longer a "Windows Network" under Networks since smb1 has been disabled on most modern systems.
There are two ways the Linux guest can discover network hosts: Avahi and WS-Discovery
On Ubuntu make sure both of these are installed:
sudo apt install avahi-daemon
sudo apt install wsdd

On the NAS make sure Bonjour ( avahi compatible ) and WS-Discovery are enabled.
Based on what I've been told it's under the NAS Control Panel:
Control Panel > File Services > SMB > Enable WS-Discovery
Control Panel > File Services > Avanaced > Enable Bonjour service discovery

Image from Synology NAS DSM v7.1

I've taken the liberty of editing your answer with a screenshot directly from my Synology NAS DSM v7.1.

Installing wsdd helped a bit, one of my printers now shows up, but not the NAS unfortunately (NAS is already configured with all settings as above, I've had it years and all file sharing options have always been enabled on it, at time of writing it has >1 year uptime, I never even touch it, it just works). Everything is fine with WIndows and Mac and was fine with 23.10 so don't think it's a NAS setting.

Can you ping the NAS from Linux using it's Bonjour host name - host name with a .local at the end? Something like this: ping -c3 disktation.local

No, get name or service not found
